# How do I load order dependent support files in Rspec without explicitly requiring the dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

In my Ruby on Rails project I have some files in `spec/support` that are dependent on other files within the same directory.

```rb
#spec/support/page_objects/foo.rb

class Foo
  include Bar
end
```

```rb
#spec/support/page_objects/bar/bar.rb

module Bar
  def hello_world
    "Hello World"
  end
end
```

In order for `Foo.new.hello_world` to work in a spec, I must explicitly prefix the dependent file with `require_relative("bar/bar")`.

```rb
#spec/support/page_objects/foo.rb

require_relative("bar/bar")

class Foo
  include Bar
end
```

I would prefer not to have to explicitly call `require` in all of my dependent files.

All of my `spec/support` files are loaded per this line of the `spec/rails_helper.rb`.

```rb
#spec/rails_helper.rb

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec", "support", "**", "*.rb")].sort.each { |f| require f }
```

I have determined that changing this line and explicitly loading dependencies first, will work.. But I am looking for a cleaner more long term solution.

I do not want to have to explicitly call `require` in all of my dependent files, nor do I want to have to name all of my dependencies in the above block for the sake of load order.

I just want it to work typical to how `app/models` works when using dependencies in development.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could [autoload](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths) spec/support with `config.autoload_paths << "spec/support"` in config/environments/test.rb but at this point I'd begin questioning why your test classes are getting so complex. Is your production code too rigid? Could the test classes be replaced with more flexible production classes and test factories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the auto-loader to load constants:

```
# config/environments/test.rb
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('spec/support')
```

Its behavior differs slightly if we are talking about Zeitwerk or the classic autoloader. But adding a path to the autoloader paths means that the auto loader will look for `Foo` in `spec/support/foo.rb` as well as `app/**/foo.rb`.

But the real question is why your using classes/modules so extensively instead of RSpec's higher level constructs such as [shared contexts](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) or factories.

Comment: It appears that the `config.autoload_paths` is not changeable via environment config per 5.2 docs

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html


`config.autoload_paths is not changeable from environment-specific configuration files.` 
I don't know if that is absolutly still the case in 6.0, but `config/application.rb` is the recommend file to change `config.autoload_paths` for 6.0 

`The array of autoload paths can be extended by mutating config.autoload_paths, in config/application.rb, but nowadays this is discouraged.`   Works for me!

Comment: @ChrisLaBarge Autoloading changed considerably in Rails 6. If you do it in config/application.rb then production will see your test directories, best not to do that.

Comment: @Schwern I edited the approved answer to conditionally append if in test environment.  Unless I am mistaken, there is no way of doing it in `config/environments/test.rb`

Comment: @ChrisLaBarge Are you sure? Works For Me!™ Check `Rails.configuration.autoload_paths`. Note that in your case it would be `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('spec/support/page_objects')`. But again, this feels like the wrong way.

Comment: @Schwern. Pretty sure! The path is only available in `RAILS_ENV=test`.  And I no longer have to use `require` in my `spec/support/` files.

Comment: @ChrisLaBarge Are you sure you can't put it into config/environments/test.rb? It works in Rails 6.1.